# Problems uploading Js files in SiteAssets library through browser but same gets uploaded when tried on the server

Tags: browser-compatibility, drag-and-drop

[image: Adding a js file through a browser , accessing the site on public URL]

[image: drag and drop error]

These two images the problem . However, if I try to upload the files after copying them on the server , same gets upload correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser is giving this error?

Comment: All the browsers: Chrome, Mozilla, IE

Comment: I hope somebody can answer this...

Comment: I have been able to figure out more that js files doe snot get uploaded only in the office network but the same gets uploaded from other internet connections. Can anybody suggest what can be the cause?

Comment: Is this issue only with js files?

Comment: Yes... there is issue only with js files..

Comment: Is it some security policy of your company to not let you upload js files?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Central Administration** => **Security** => **Define blocked file types**
and check the file types which are blocked. If js is there that means you will not be able to upload js files to it. If js is not there then maybe it's your organization's security standard which is not allowing you to upload js files.

Comment: This is not the case as if it would have been the case, I would not have been able to upload from the server also.

Comment: Try opening the SiteAssets library in explorer and then copy js files.

Comment: It will not upload in the Explorer view also.